# how to scaffold complex types in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I have a User class that has a property of type Login, which is just another simple class composed of two string properties, Username and Password.

What would be the correct (and best) way to make MVC3 scaffold the Login property too when adding a Scaffolded View for the User class?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448938/displaying-complex-types-in-asp-net-mvc3-rc2) related to this right here on StackOverflow, but it asked MVC2, and since I've read that MVC3 improved scaffolding a lot, I want to know if there's a better way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This article shows how to do what you're looking for exactly (one to many relationship):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx

Steven Sanderson is also crazy good with this kind of stuff.  Check out his MvcScaffolding project with a One to Many relationship scaffolder:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/

Comment: thanks, but while a good suggestion, it's not really an answer. I'm looking for a code sample or a link to an article that shows how to do it. Thanks though

Comment: The link I posted is a step by step walkthrough of how to do it.  It's part of a longer tutorial on his site, just use the top links to navigate.

Comment: Edited with the exact thing you want to do.