# How to scaffold complex types with EF in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I wonder if there is more suitable approached to auto-scaffold complex type with several One-To-One and One-To-Many relations. Let's say I have type done with Code-First.

```
public class Bank
{
    [Key]
    public Guid BankId { get; set; }
    public virtual BankProfile Profile { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<BankAccount> Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AutomatedTellerMachine> BankAutomatedTellerMachines { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BankOperationHistory> BankOperationsHistory { get; set; } 

    public Bank()
    {
        BankId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Accounts = new List<BankAccount>();
        BankAutomatedTellerMachines = new List<AutomatedTellerMachine>();
        BankOperationsHistory = new List<BankOperationHistory>();
    }
}
```

And I want to create some Create view where ALL fields from Bank-class and sub-classes like BankProfile-class are included. However, just simple scaffold Controller doesn't work and returns something like this view: (Html.Helpers here too...)

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Bank</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I solved it with creating the VERY big form manually and data sent from VIew to Controller as a lot of string, int, double types. Is there a way to do something like this?:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgery]
public ActionResult CreateBank(Bank bank, BankProfile profile, List<BankAccount> accounts){...}
```

I found something similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864939/how-to-scaffold-complex-types-in-asp-net-mvc3), but it doesn't show how to place all inputs for Bank\BankProfile in the one form.

Comment: Take a look at the ViewModel pattern. Basically, create a top level model called CreateBankViewModel and include all the classes and collections in there (Bank, BankProfile, Accounts, etc). See http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/